# Are there official terms in any cultures for vampire hideouts?

Tags: monsters, vampires

I've been thinking about what sorts of monsters would realistically be in a haunted house and I wound up wondering if there was an official word for the sorts of places where vampires lived. Is there?

Answer (score 2):

In English, you often see "lair" used. You can see a bunch as [book titles](https://www.google.com/search?q=vampire+lair&tbm=bks&prmd=ivsnmbtz&start=0), even going back to the [19th century](https://books.google.com/books?id=64A2AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA129&dq=vampire%27s+lair&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0#v=onepage&q=vampire%27s%20lair&f=false).

Lair, of course, isn't only used with vampires, but I think that's history enough to establish it as an acceptable use for them.

Comment: In *Dracula* Bram Stoker uses "lair" several times to refer to the Count's hiding places.

Comment: @Chenmunka That would certainly solidify its usage. The link I posted was just a few years older. I haven't checked the OED yet to see if there were earlier usages.